# Bluetooth low energy - ISSC Transparent UART

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to a device which has an ISSC transparent UART. When I list the services of the proprietary services, I can only see two characteristics, not the four I expect. I can see ISSC_AIR_PATCH and ISSC_UPDATE_CONNECTION_PARAMETER, but not ISSC_TRANS_TX or ISSC_TRANS_RX.

(I can see the Generic and Device services).

The TX and RX characteristics are not reported - either to my own code, or to a Bluetooth LE Scanner, using Android or Windows apps (not tried iOS yet).

Is there something I need to do, turn on? I have a sequence chart for android and one for iOS. Unfortunately the android one is classic BT (uses RFComm), but the iOS one is BLE - it has one cryptic line I don't understand "Set Client Configuration: Enabled" , leading me to believe I am missing a step, but I haven't been able to find anything more about that line in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats still actual, but:

I've seen similar situation with my iSSC BTLE device. It seems vendors sometimes renaming RX and TX characteristics to their custom Guids.

In my case I had a separate service with two custom characteristics.
Occasionally these appears to be write and read(update) controls of the UART.